# Android Studio how to import non-project library?

Tags: android, import, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml

I'm using Android Studio

My project needs import google vision api

following

[image: 1]
    com/google/vision/v1a1pha1

how can i do to import java files on my project?

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click the `java` folder and create a new package `com.google.vision.v1alpha1`
2. Drop/paste your java files on the package and it gets imported.